# Debugging not running on PyCharm for my Django project

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am not able to run with debug option for my Django project after an recent update of PyCharm.

The last line of stacktrace gives error

```
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

the first few lines of stacktrace gives error

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
```

Here is the full stacktrace -

```
pydev debugger: process 21976 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 181.5087.37)
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Thread 0x000070000ee34000 (most recent call first):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 101 in _on_run
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 303 in run
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000070000e931000 (most recent call first):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 365 in _on_run
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 303 in run
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x000070000e42e000 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1238 in current_thread
  ...

Thread 0x00007fffb4ace380 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 832 in get_data
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 764 in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/Work/python/repos/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 579 in patch_thread
  File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/Work/python/repos/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 178 in ignores
  File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/Work/python/repos/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 976 in patch_all
  File "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/Work/python/repos/manage.py", line 4 in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18 in execfile
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1068 in run
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1658 in main
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664 in <module>

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Comment: Is it possible to run the server?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yes simple run is working perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same problem. In my case, it's because I was using gevent. There's an option in the PyCharm settings under Build, Execution, Deployment -> Python Debugger. I enabled "Gevent compatible", and debugging started working again.

Comment: yeah, it;s maybe useful to fix this error, but it not run into where breakpoint is put. It's run like normally

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problem with starting a django 2.2 project with python 3.6. Troy Hoffmans solution could start the server in debug Mode, but the breakpoints were then ignored. So I activatet "Collect run-time types information for code insight" in PyCharm settings under Build, Execution, Deployment -> Python Debugger.